# Modeling a probabilistic game with changing probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, card-games

I am trying to model a simple game (a more complex problem I am working on reduces to it).

1. You roll an $n$-sided dice labeled 1 to $n$. (This can be a normal 6-sided dice if you'd like.)
2. If the dice shows **1**, you draw a card from a deck of $m$ cards labeled 1 to $m$. (This can be a normal 52-card deck if you'd like.) You record which card you drew, replace it in the deck, and shuffle.
3. This process repeats until you draw a card you have previously seen.

The question: what is the **distribution of the expected length of this game, in terms of the number of dice rolls?**

---

I am able to model the individual sub-games without an issue:

**Game 1**, the dice game, is geometrically distributed with $p=1/n$. On average, we expect to see a **1** every $n$ throws.

**Game 2**, the card game, is a bit more complex, but we can model it like this:

- On our $(i+1)$-th draw, we have already seen $i$ cards, all of which are unique (if not, the game would already be over).
- Therefore, the probability the given card $i+1$ matches one of the previous cards is $\frac{i}{m}$ for a deck of size $m$.
- Factoring in the probability of *not* having already won, the distribution of winning the game on draw $i$ is

$$
P(i) = \frac{m!/(m-i)!}{m^i} \cdot \frac{i}{m}
$$

(The numerator of the left fraction is just the number of permutations of $i$ items from $m$ items.)

I can't find a closed form for the expected value of this PDF, but it matches simulations given a value of $m$. For example, consider the standard case of $n=6$ and $m=52$.

- We expect a **1** on the dice every 6 rolls.
- We expect to draw a duplicate card after 9.7 draws, on average. (Solved numerically in Mathematica and confirmed in simulation.)
- So, we expect the game to last $\approx 58$ rolls on average, since we can multiply expectations of independent events.

But what is the actual *distribution* of game lengths?

Here's some simulation data. I play the game 100,000 times:

[image: simulation results]

The simulation code looks like this:

```
def play_game():
    cards_seen = set()
    for i in it.count(1):
        dice = random.randint(1, 6)
        if dice != 1:
            continue

        card = random.randint(1, 52)
        if card in cards_seen:
            return i, 1 + len(cards_seen)

        cards_seen.add(card)
```

Statistics from the simulation:

- Mean number of turns: 58.19
- ...median: 54
- Mean number of cards drawn: 9.69
- ...median: 9
- Implied number of turns/per card (i.e., dice rolls 1): 6.005

This looks very familiar (i.e., vaguely negative-binomial), but the changing probability of pulling a matching card makes such an analysis tricky.

I know the combination of distributions can be computed via [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions), but I'm not clear how I would apply that here, since these two distributions are not really independent — whether we play the card subgame is directly dependent on the results of the dice subgame.

I believe this game can be modeled as a Markov chain, but I'm not sure if that helps with the analysis.

- We have dice states $D_k$ and card states $C_k$.
- We start at state $D_1$ and move to state $C_1$ with probability $1/6$, or remain at state $D_1$ with probability $5/6$.
- At some state $C_k$, we end the game with probability $P(k)$ from above, and move to state $D_{k+1}$ with probability $1-P(k)$.

Now the question reduces to finding the distribution of the number of steps in this chain.

Comment: There's no such thing as "the distribution of the expected length".

Comment: Sorry, I guess I mean to ask how we can model this distribution, ideally with “common” distributions. This may not be possible, I recognize.

Comment: The absorption time of a Markov chain does have a "common" name: the discrete phase-type distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with deck game only.

Call $T$ the random time (# of deck extraction) where we see the first duplicate.
We can use this formula for expectation: $$E[T]=\sum_{k=0}^{m}P(T>k)$$ and observe that $P(T>k)=\frac{m!}{(m-k)!}\frac{1}{m^k}$, as it requires that in k extractions, we get k different cards.

Adding the die-part, will just delay the inevitable by a factor of $n$ on average.

$$$$

For the distribution part lets introduce $S$ for the random time of the overall game and $X_k$ for the numbers of 1s in the first k rolls (it is a Binomial).

So we have that:
$$
P(S=k)=\sum_{p=0}^{\min\{k-1, m\}} P(S=k \ \bigcap \ X_{k-1}=p)
$$

A bit of intuition. If S=k, it means that the k-th iteration gets a 1 with a card already seen, while all previous extractions were unique.
But how many extractions? Lets cycle through them leveraging $X_k-1$.

Finally we get the following (unsimplified) expression:
$$
 P(S=k \ \bigcap \ X_{k-1}=p) = \binom{k-1}{p}\ 
\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^p\ 
\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^ {(k-1)-p}\ 
\frac{1}{n}\ \ 
\frac{1}{m^p}\ \ 
\binom{m}{p} \ p\ !\ \ 
\frac{p}{m}
$$

$$$$
I leave some R code that I have used to view results.

```
prob_k_p <- function(k, p, n=6, m=52){
  choose(k-1, p) * (n^(-p)) * (((n-1)/n)^(k-1-p)) / n *
  m^(-p) * choose(m, p) * factorial(p) * p/m
}

prob_k <- function(k, n=6, m=52){
  temp.1 <- sapply(0:min(k-1,m), prob_k_p, k=k, n=n, m=m)
  return(sum(temp.1))
}


n<- 6; m <- 52

n * sum(factorial(m)/factorial(m-(0:m))*m^(-(0:m)))
plot(2:200, sapply(2:200, prob_k, n=n, m=m))
```

[image]

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, and is probably as close as we're going to get. I ran a million simulations and this expression matches perfectly. Fooling around a bit more in Mathematica, it doesn't look like we can make too many more useful simplifications.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it provides an exact closed form that perfectly matches simulated data. The solution from @awkward comes extremely close (and is a more satisfying result), so is an excellent (and more ergonomic) model for this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can model the general case as a Markov chain whose state at any time is the number of distinct cards that have been observed up to that time or (conveniently) $\ m+1\ $ if a duplicate card has been observed.  This chain has $\ m+2\ $ states, $\ 0,1,\dots,m+1\ $, with transition matrix $\ P\ $ given by
$$
P(S_{t+1}=x\,|\,S_t=y)=\cases{\frac{n-1}{n}&if $\ 0\le x=y\le m$\\
\frac{m-y}{mn}&if $\ 0\le x=y+1\le m$\\
\frac{y}{mn}&if $\ x=m+1\ \text{ and }\ y\le m$\\
1&if $\ x=y=m+1\ $\\
0&otherwise.}
$$
If $\ e_k\ $ is the expected number of further dice rolls until the game terminates given that the current state is $\ k\ $, then $\ e_k\ $ must satisfy the first order difference equation
$$
e_k=1+\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)e_k+\left(\frac{m-k}{mn}\right)e_{k+1}
$$
with terminal condition $\ e_{m+1}=0\ $. This has solution
$$
e_t=n\sum_{k=t}^m\frac{(m-t)!}{(m-k)!\,m^{k-t}}\ ,
$$
and, in particular,
$$
e_0=n\sum_{k=0}^m~\frac{m!}{(m-k)!\,m^k}\ .
$$
For $\ n=6,m=52\ $ this gives
$$
e_0\approx58.31\ ,
$$
correct to two decimal places.

**Correction**

My original expression for $\ e_t\ $ was missing a factor $\ \frac{m^t(m-t)!}{m!}\ $, which I have now included. Since the value of this factor is $\ 1\ $at $\ t=0\ $, the correction doesn't affect the value given for $\ e_0\ $.

Answer (score 1):

This example maybe gives some insight how to calculate it. Using the same Markov chain as lonza leggiera, we can calculate the Jordan form of the transition matrix (the non-absorbing part). Unfortunately there are unit-blocks, when you exponentiate you get binomial coefficients.

$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
25 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 25 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 25 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 25 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 25 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 25
\end{array}\right)
= \\
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
120 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
25 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 25 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 25 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 25 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 25 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 25
\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
\frac{1}{120} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{24} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$

Here's the code (It has some remnants of my previous method where I made an absorbing state for each amount of cards seen before being absorbed because I thought that might be helpful):

```
def f(n, m):
    #state = (distinct cards seen, seen same), seen sames are absorbing
    states = sorted([(k,0) for k in range(m+1)], key=lambda t:t[1]) + [(m+1,1)]
    #old way
    #sorted([(k,w) for k in range(m+1) for w in range(2)], key=lambda t:t[1])
    sToI = {s:i for i,s in enumerate(states)}
    mat = matrix(QQ, len(states))
    for i,s in enumerate(states):
        if s[1]==1:
            mat.add_to_entry(i, i, 1)
        else:
            mat.add_to_entry(i, i, (n-1)/n)
            if s[0]<m: mat.add_to_entry(i, sToI[(s[0]+1, 0)], (m-s[0])/(n*m))
            mat.add_to_entry(i, sToI[(m+1, 1)], s[0]/(n*m))
    print(states)
    show(1/(m*n), m*n*mat)
    D, S = (m*n*mat[:m+1, :m+1]).jordan_form(transformation=True)
    show(S * D * S^(-1))
    show(S, D, S^(-1))
    fundMat = (matrix.identity(m+1)-mat[:m+1, :m+1])^(-1)
    R = mat[:m+1, m+1:]
    #show(fundMat, R)
    pMat = fundMat*R
    #show(pMat)
    #return tuple(pMat[0])

    
    
print (f(6, 5))
```

I added the computer calculation of the probabilities (and cleaned up the code a bit):

```
def cumuF(n, m, uptoK=100):
    mat = matrix(QQ, m+2)
    for j in range(m+1):
        mat.add_to_entry(j, j, (n-1)/n)
        if j<m: mat.add_to_entry(j, j+1, (m-j)/(n*m))
        mat.add_to_entry(j, m+1, j/(n*m))
    mat.add_to_entry(m+1, m+1, 1)
    ret = []
    A = mat
    for k in range(uptoK):
        ret.append(A[0][-1])
        A *= mat
    return ret

    
F = cumuF(6, 52, 200)
ps = [F[i]-F[i-1] for i in range(1, len(F))]

show(bar_chart(ps))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's say one step in the process consists of either (1) rolling a number greater than $1$, with probability $1-1/n$; or (2) rolling a $1$ followed by drawing card $i$, for $1 \le i \le m$, with probability $1/(mn)$. Define $T$ to be the number of the step on which we first draw a duplicate card, and  define $p_k$ to be the probability that we have *not* drawn any duplicates by the $k$th step; equivalently, $p_k = P(T > k)$.  By a well-known theorem, $$E(T) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(T>k) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k$$

Now let $f(x)$ be the exponential generating function of $p_k$, i.e.
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{p_k}{k!} x^k$$
In a sequence of $k$ steps with no duplicates, we can have any number of occurrences of rolling a number greater than $1$, and any card drawn either zero or one times (combined with rolling a $1$).  So
$$f(x) = e^{(1-1/n)x}\left(1 + \frac{x}{mn} \right)^m$$
Taking advantage of the indentity
$$\int_0^{\infty} x^k e^{-x} \; dx = k!$$
we have
$$\begin{align} 
E(T) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} f(x) \; dx \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} \cdot e^{(1-1/n)x}\left(1 + \frac{x}{mn} \right)^m \; dx \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x/n}\left(1 + \frac{x}{mn} \right)^m \; dx
\end{align}$$
In the case $n=6$, $m=52$, Mathematica evaluates the integral as $58.3102$.

Comment: This looks really interesting. I'm not getting that integral to converge, however — is there a typo in your final expression?

Comment: @baum Oops, yes, there was a typo in the integral and in the definition of $f(x)$.  When I fixed it I also added a (slightly) simplified version of the final integral.  Thanks.

Comment: Taking the derivative of the expression inside the integral (so, $E''(T)$) gives an extremely close approximation of the simulated distribution. Very cool — need to think a little more through your explanation but I appreciate the analysis!

Edit: it's actually the negative derivative that works. i.e., $\exp(-x/n)\cdot(1+x/mn)^m\cdot x / (n (mn + x))$

Comment: @baum The beauty of a generating function is that everything there is to know about the distribution is in there somewhere, if you can just figure out how to find it. ;-)